# How to display 5 multiples per line?

Tags: java, formatting, integer, printf, output

I have to display a table for detecting multiples for 2 numbers.

I'm having trouble formatting my output.

The multiples should be printed left-aligned in columns 8 characters wide, 5 multiples per line.

I know it should be simple but i cant figure out how to display 5 multiples per line.

can anyone help?

```
public class Multiples_Loop_Table {

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    int total = 0;


//table heading
    System.out.println("     Integers from 300 to 200");

    System.out.println("   -----------------------------");

    for (int high = 300; high >= 200 && high <= 300; )
    {
        if ( (high % 11 == 0) != (high % 13 == 0))
        {
            System.out.printf("%-8d", high);
            total += high;
        }
        high = high - 1;

    }
    //Total of all integers added togather
    System.out.println("\nHere's the total for all integers: " + total );

    //System.out.println("Here's the total number of integers found: " + );
    //for every high add 1 to ?
```

example:

299     297     275     273     264
260     253     247     242     234
231     221     220     209     208

Comment: you should give an example of desired output.

Comment: seems what you need to do is to use a variable, say, cols (initiated to 0), then you increase it by 1 in the if block after the printf() line. but before the printf() line, you test it to see if it equals to 5. if the test is true, you print out a newline and reset cols to 0.

Comment: @Shiping ah! sorry about that. Fixed! you're advice was helpful i needed another variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could print a new line every n amount of times and reset it to 0 using a col variable to keep track.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

   int total = 0;
   int col   = 0;

   // table heading
   System.out.println("     Integers from 300 to 200");

   System.out.println("   -----------------------------");

   for (int high = 300; high >= 200 && high <= 300;) {
       if ((high % 11 == 0) != (high % 13 == 0)) {

           if (col == 5) {
               System.out.println();
               col = 0;
           }

           System.out.printf("%-8d", high);
           total += high;
           col++;
       }
       high = high - 1;
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks adding col variable really helped.