# Java-How to Display Numbers 5 Times Before a New Line

Tags: java

So I know I have to get the remainder in order for this to work. However, it works perfectly except for the first line where it gives me 6 instead of 5 for the first line. I think this is happening because 0 is considered a multiple of 5, but I am not really sure of how to get around this. I looked at [How to display 5 multiples per line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42009106/how-to-display-5-multiples-per-line) but I am having trouble seeing how to fix my code using that as it doesn't appear like they had the first line being messed up issue. For example, if I enter 17 into the positive number it gives 6 numbers for the first line and then 5 for the rest. Then it gives the remaining ones which is what I want. For the average part you can type anything as I am going to work on that later. So the format should be something like this:

4.50, 5.56, 2.73, 8.59, 7.75,

...

5.34, 3.65,

Here is my code and thanks for the help:

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ArrayFun {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayFun a = new ArrayFun();
    }
    public ArrayFun() { 
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        // Get input from the user 
        System.out.print("Enter a positive number: "); 
        int limit = input.nextInt();
        // Get input from the user 
        System.out.print("Enter the lower bound for average: "); 
        double lowerBound = input.nextDouble();
        // Generate an array of random scores
        double[] allScores = generateRandomArrayOfScores(limit);
        // Display scores, wrapped every 5 numbers with two digit precision 
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00"); 
        displayArrayOfScores(allScores , df);
        // Calculate the average of the scores and display it to the screen
        //double average = calculateAverage(lowerBound , allScores); //
        System.out.print("Average of " + limit + " scores "); 
        System.out.print("(dropping everything below " + df.format(lowerBound) + ") "); 
        //System.out.println("is " + df.format(average) );//
    }
    private double[] generateRandomArrayOfScores(int num) {
        double[] scores=new double[num];
        for (int i=0;i<scores.length;++i) {
            double number=Math.random()*100.0;
            scores[i]=number;
        }
        return scores;
    }
    private void displayArrayOfScores(double[] scores, DecimalFormat format) {
        System.out.println("Scores:");
        for (int i=0;i<scores.length;++i) {
            String num=format.format(scores[i]);
            if ((i%5==0)&&(i!=0)) {
                System.out.println(num+", ");
            }
            else{
                System.out.print(num+", ");
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }


}
```

Comment: Your question is about Java, yet you tagged JavaScript. Please be aware that Java and JavaScript are *not* the same thing. I've corrected your tags for you.

Comment: Thanks Obsidian Age as I completely missed that, I do know that Java and JavaScript are different, I just did not see that. My fault, if I would have seen that, I would have corrected it. Also, Scary Wombat, I currently do not know how to use the debugger, but I am going to learn that in a few days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is indeed the 0, exactly this part `(i%5==0)&&(i!=0)`. Replace this by `i%5==4` and it should work. It is because `System.out.println(...)` makes the new line after printing the string and if you count 0,1,2,3,4,5 those are 6 numbers, because you treat 0 differently. The last number in the groups of 5 has a modulo of 4. `(i+1)%5==0` would work too fo course, it is the equivalent. Alternatively you could do an empty `System.out.println()` using your condition and print the number as the others afterwards.

Comment: Thanks as it solved my problem how ever I am still confused on why it solves my problem, I am confused because it would be saying if the remainder is 4, but is more referred to a modulo?

Comment: Your condition wasn't too bad, as noted you could just do a System.out.println() in the if and put the code in the else part after it (removing else itself). Maybe this makes more sense to you. Modulo is cycling and if you start at 1 it would be as you expected, but not if you start to count at 0.

Comment: Oh ok that makes sense now. Thanks for the help.